# Google CSE - search box that redirects to the page with results

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

guys.

I'm a bit confused with Google CSE manual and can't understand some of its basic functionality.

So, I have created a free custom search profile and all I got is the only code snippet, this one:

```
<div id="cse" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'ru', style : google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchOptions = {};
    var googleAnalyticsOptions = {};
    googleAnalyticsOptions['queryParameter'] = 'q';
    googleAnalyticsOptions['categoryParameter'] = '';
    customSearchOptions['googleAnalyticsOptions'] = googleAnalyticsOptions;  var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl(
      '001098741616107095995:xeqdxoqdue8', customSearchOptions);
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');
  }, true);
</script>
```

This snippet creates the google custom search controls in the specified div. That's why this snippet is probably going to be situated in the search results page, e. g. www.site.com/search.html

But what I'm going to implement is the search box in the sidebar on every page of my website. User can type-in the search query into that search box wherever he is and get straight to the result page www.site.com/search.html with the set of matches awaiting him.

How can I do that?

Looking through the manual has no effect for me, I'm missing something, but can't figure out what exactly...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The google search works by getting the search query from a URL parameter. You just need to create a form that posts get parameters to your results page. The name of your search field needs to match the one in the URL bar normally a q like www.yoursite.com?q=your+search

```
<form action="http://www.yoursite.com/resulspage" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" value="Seacrh" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've placed the code from my question on some page (domain.com/search) and made manual request like domain/com/search?q=php+cli+app and after the page is loaded I see only the rendered empty search prompt. No search was performed... It seems that my code works only like a widget without any external queries possible. maybe it's a wrong code?

Comment: by using this method can `auto-complete` be enabled

Answer (score 0):

here something that worked for me. ( if I understood correctly your Q )

> src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
>       
>         .........
>
> ```
>   customSearchControl.draw('google_search');
>
>    <? if (isset($keyword)) { ?>     
>      customSearchControl.execute('<?=$keyword?>'); <? } ?>    
>    }
> google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
> </script>
> ```